# Default value for toggle button in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, toggle, togglebutton

I have a toggle button with multiple options.
I have to set a default option to be true to begin with and this value has to be returned.
I implement the button in this way

```
        <form novalidate>
          <mat-button-toggle-group name="testSelect" [(ngModel)]="testSelect">
            <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let item of options" [nxValue]="item.headline">
              
                {{ item.headline }} 
            </mat-button-toggle>
          </mat-button-toggle-group>
          <p>
            Current Value: {{ testSelect }}
          </p>
        </form>
```

ts

```
export class CComponent{
testSelect: string;
options = [
{
  
  headline: 'apple'
},
{
 
  headline: 'mango'
},
{
  
  headline: 'orange'
}
]; 
}
```

Regarding the default option, I want the last option of the group to be preselected and its value must be recorded. Now in my case, the value is recorded only after a button is selcted.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I want the last option of the group to be preselected and its value must be recorded. Now in my case, the value is recorded only after a button is selcted. @VimalPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `value` attribute for default selection.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="testSelect" [(ngModel)]="testSelect" value="textSelect">
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item.headline">
        {{ item.headline }}
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

And in your component assign the value to `textSelect` which you want as default selected.

```
testSelect: string="orange";
```

Reference from this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991657/1289713).

Comment: ,I have one question in regards to the angular material table can you please help here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an

Comment: I way to default select multiple values

Comment: @HamzaHaddad Can you explain your problem statement in detail?